# Why do Asp.net web project have garbage values in the url?

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

I have tried googling and searching for this issue on SO - but have had little success - primarily because I am not sure whether I am searching right.

I am working on an ASP.Net Web Application **Project** (not website) using Visual Studio 2008, C# and Cassini for testing.

However, everytime I run the site, I get a URL such as:

```
http://localhost:8671/(S(saifdk55xyhalrqbstrtrdiw))/SubjectClassTeacher/Default.aspx
```

Even if I modify the URL and try to go to:

```
http://localhost:8671/SubjectClassTeacher/Default.aspx
```

I am redirected back to this URL.

The garbage value in the center: **(S(saifdk55xyhalrqbstrtrdiw))** keeps changing every few times I compile and I have no idea why it gets injected or how to disable it.

Could anyone throw any light on this issue?
Primarily, I would like to know why this happens and how do I disable this.

Because this happens when I deploy the website on IIS as well.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a clever feature in ASP.NET* called **[cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)**. It works by injecting your session ID into every URL, so ASP.NET can tell the difference between user A who visits a page, and user B who visits the same page. Normally this is accomplished with cookies, but this approach removes the dependency on the end-user having them enabled.

From MSDN:

> ...you don't have to change anything in your ASP.NET application to enable cookieless sessions, except the following configuration setting.
>
> `<sessionState cookieless="true" />`

*The concept is not exclusive to ASP.NET, but it is baked into ASP.NET and - as you've discovered - can be turned on with no particular effort on the part of the developer.

Comment: PHP uses query variables (at the end, after the '?') which is essentially the same thing. +1.

Comment: on a side note, please don't use cookieless sesssions. Makes it very simple to do session fixation attacks.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick reply. I just put cookieless="false" in my web.config and it disappeared.

Thanks again :)